# Custom Field in Sharepoint 2010 with multiple Link and Asset Picker

Tags: sharepoint-2010, custom-fields, custom-field-type

I'm looking for a solution for a problem...
I need a Sharepoint Field wich contains multiple link, stored in a simple way (like ';' separation).
Does anybody know if there are project 'bout custom field with multiple link and Asset picker to choose the link?

I'd like to use the Asset Picker to choose a single link, and then catch the result and append it to my custom field value.. I googled a lot looking for "how" call the asset picker from code... I hope is something like a simple dialog, but i cannot understand how to do it!

Thanks for any suggestion (about projects similar to this or how to use the asset picker)!!

Comment: SharePoint related questions would be very welcome on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) - you might want to consider posting it there, or better still asking for it to be migrated.